# Run an external App from WebAssembly

Tags: c++, chromium, webassembly

I'm trying to get my hands on WebAssembly so I'd like to ask about its capabilities.

1) I'd like to run an external application on a local disk. But according to WebAssembly docs all we can do is work through stdio.h and with preloaded file in virtual file systems. So Any chance to run an external application on a disk through Java/WebAssembly?

2) Is there any support for IPC that other applications could be interacted through Java/WebAssembly?

Or any of these functionality could be achieved differently?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Browsers are sandboxed for security reasons and WebAssembly has no effect on that

Comment: That's correct but mostly I want to know if there are any workarounds?

Comment: Apart from using some browser-specific (unsafe) features you'll have to apply the same workflows as without WebAssembly - use (Web)Extensions or set up a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WebAssembly is run in a web browser it will be sandboxed and have all the usual restrictions any other web page would have.

If you run WASM in Node, then you could call out to Node and then get Node to call out to other processes.

Lastly, there's at least one [stand alone implementation of the WASM VM](https://github.com/AndrewScheidecker/WAVM) (and probably more), and presumably you could modify it to be able to interact with any other program on your system.

Comment: That's one of the ways. I decided to go with NativeMessaging and register app that will able to communicate with browser. Thanks for your reply I'll mark it as answer